# K8s porforward to external resource through pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, portforwarding, azure-cognitive-services

I have K8s cluster in Azure, and have some configured cognitive services in Azure. These services have disabled public access but open for internal private network (private endpoints).

So, these resource are available from K8s cluster (I am able to access (telnet/curl) to them) but unavailable from my local machine.

Is it possible to execute portforwarding to Azure resources through pod? For example - access to 5432 psql service or 443 for some cognitive services?

I had tried something like this:

`kubectl port-forward --address localhost -n XXX  pod/XXX 8083:443`

and tried to send request to localhost:8083 but unsuccessfully

Comment: if the pod is a proxy , it can do the middleware function to access other resources .
+ 
Clarify the error when tried localhost:8083 , also which protocol and logs of kubectl port-forward itself

Comment: No, pod is not configured as proxy. It is just some "working" pod which is located in network, which have access to Azure services. So, looks like I need some separate pod with something wich will be proxy for me?

Comment: Can't you just create a working pod and run the application in the pod instead of locally? Then the port-forwarding scheme would work. I'm not quite sure what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: yes, as PortFWD only work as port natting not router , so you need to use proxies to access remote services

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Tamer Elfeky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16317045/tamer-elfeky) and [prosto.vint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905620/prosto-vint) posting your discussions into answer section to help other community members.

> Port forwarding works just as **Port Natting** not as **Router**. To
> access the remote services, Proxies are required.